# DS.RESTAdapter targetting localhost instead the specified host

Tags: ember.js

I have defined my RESTAdapter as follows

```
Metabuyer.RequisitionsAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: "apps/purchasing",
    host: 'http://metabuyer.apiary-mock.com'
});

Metabuyer.RequisitionsSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    normalizePayload: function(payload) {
        return payload['data'];
    }
});
```

when loading the page, 
i received this following error

```
GET http://localhost:9000/requisitions 404 (Not Found)
```

it didn't target

```
http://metabuyer.apiary-mock.com/apps/purchasing/requisitions
```

Before this, i define my handlebars, router, route, model, store and the adapter with 'requisition' singular (without appended 's') it works fine.

it targetted

```
http://metabuyer.apiary-mock.com/apps/purchasing/requisitions
```

it actually left me wondering why the RESTAdapter append an 'S' (requisitionS) at the end of the URL but because it works(and also, that's the URL from the mock API) , i didnt really care about it too much.

Now i want to follow the naming convention, so i change the name of my handlebars, router, route, model, store and the adapter to 'requisitions' and then the error happens.

Thank you for your help in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because the adapter and serializer should not be pluralized, see: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/

It should be `Metabuyer.RequisitionAdapter` and `Metabuyer.RequisitionSerializer`

By default ember data will pluralize the models name to use for the path. So for the `Requisition` model it will make a request to `/requisitions`

If you want to override that you can change the [`pathForType`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_pathForType) property on the `DS.RESTAdapter` and return whatever path you'd like.